# How to restrict passed parameter in method

Tags: c#, design-patterns, methods, parameter-passing, restrict

My question is in sample code.
How to i restrict developers for passing true parameter. I try something about generics but i couldn't fix.

The important thing here is i want to restrict in Compile Time. So i know how can i prevent in Runtime.

```
namespace TheLiving
{
    public interface IFood
    {
        int Protein { get; set; }
        int Carbohydrate { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IMeat : IFood
    {
        int Nitrogen { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IVegetable : IFood
    {
        int Vitamin { get; set; }
    }


    public class Veal : IMeat
    {
        public int Protein { get; set; }
        public int Carbohydrate { get; set; }
        public int Nitrogen { get; set; }
    }

    public class Spinach : IVegetable
    {
        public int Protein { get; set; }
        public int Carbohydrate { get; set; }
        public int Vitamin { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IEating
    {
        void Eat(IFood food);
    }

    public class Lion : IEating
    {
        public int Protein { get; set; }
        public int Carbohydrate { get; set; }
        public int Nitrogen { get; set; }


        //But lion is eating only Meat. So any developer can pass vegatable to lion for eating. 
        //May be god is not a good developer. So i want restrict him on Compile Time!! for passing only Meat. :)
        //The important thing here is i want restrict on Compile Time not RunTime!!!
        public void Eat(IFood food)
        {
            Protein = food.Protein;
            Carbohydrate = food.Carbohydrate;
            //Nitrogen = ?? //So i know that i can cast and validate food but i want ensure this on DesignTime!!
        }
    }

    public class Sheep : IEating
    {
        public int Protein { get; set; }
        public int Carbohydrate { get; set; }
        public int Vitamin { get; set; }

        public void Eat(IFood food)
        {
            Protein = food.Protein;
            Carbohydrate = food.Carbohydrate;
            //Vitamin = food.??
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With this design its not possible, only you can do is throwing an Exception at runtime.

Comment: I think you mean _compile time_ instead of _design time_.

Comment: @Oliver yes Compile Time. Thanks for correction.

Answer (score 5):

I think you'll have to have interfaces for `IHerbivore`, `ICarnivore`, and `IOmnivore` to allow this at design time.

```
public interface IHerbivore
{
    void Eat(IVegetable food);
}

public interface ICarnivore
{
    void Eat(IMeat food);
}

public interface IOmnivore : IHerbivore, ICarnivore
{
}
```

Then your lion can be an `ICarnivore` and will only be able to eat meat

Comment: Yes its better design for this problem. Thanks. 
But in my project i couldnt change design.
I thought than may be there is a way using generic. Something like that

**void Eat<T>(T food) where T : IMeat;**

Comment: I don't understand, you could change the design of Eat to be generic but you can't change the design to introduce a couple of new interfaces?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative you can change the interface...

```
public interface IEating
{
    bool Eat(IFood food); //return wheater the eater eats the food or not
}
```

And implement the lion like:

```
public class Lion : IEating
{
    public int Protein { get; set; }
    public int Carbohydrate { get; set; }
    public int Nitrogen { get; set; }

    public bool Eat(IFood food)
    {
        IMeat meat = food as IMeat;
        if (meat != null)
        {

            Protein = meat.Protein;
            Carbohydrate = meat.Carbohydrate;
            Nitrogen = meat.Nitrogen;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice alternative, but this still only give runtime validation, not design time validation. It indicates to the programmer that its possible that the food might not be eaten and that they need to cater for that possibility though.

Comment: @SamHolder all true, just wanted to point at another design approach

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface IEating<in T> where T : IFood {

    void Eat(T food);
}

public class Lion : IEating<IMeat>, IEating<IFood> {

    public int Protein { get; set; }
    public int Carbohydrate { get; set; }
    public int Nitrogen { get; set; }

    public void Eat(IMeat food) {

        Protein = food.Protein;
        Carbohydrate = food.Carbohydrate;
        Nitrogen = food.Nitrogen;
    }

    public void Eat(IFood food) {

        var meat = food as IMeat;
        if (meat == null) return;

        Eat(meat);
    }
}

public class Sheep : IEating<IVegetable>, IEating<IFood> {

    public int Protein { get; set; }
    public int Carbohydrate { get; set; }
    public int Vitamin { get; set; }

    public void Eat(IVegetable food) {
        Protein = food.Protein;
        Carbohydrate = food.Carbohydrate;
        Vitamin = food.Vitamin;
    }

    public void Eat(IFood food) {

        var vegetable = food as IVegetable;
        if (vegetable == null) return;

        Eat(vegetable);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code has no comments. Try adding to explanatory text.

Answer (score 0):

What about [MS Code Contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/)? I would swear its Visual Studio integration add at least warnings at compile time.